# Переотправка документов, граффити, vk api

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, callback

Не могу отправить граффити и документы. Создал универсальный способ отправки фото, видео, и музыки, с помощью которого переотправляются и граффити с документами, но ВК пишет, что контент удален, возможно, я что-то не так делаю. Буду благодарен за подсказку.

```
$message=$mess;
$type=$data->object->message->attachments[0]->type;
$owner_id=$data->object->message->attachments[0]->$type->owner_id;
$photo_id=$data->object->message->attachments[0]->$type->id;
$access_key=$data->object->message->attachments[0]->$type->access_key;
$url=$data->object->message->attachments[0]->$type->url;
$request_params = [
'message' => $message,
'peer_id' => $get_id,
'url'=> $url,
'attachment'=>"{$type}{$owner_id}_{$photo_id}_{$access_key}",
'random_id' => "0",
'access_token' => $token,
'v' => '5.103'
];
$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params);
}
```

Comment: Если вы отправляете с ключом доступа от сообщества (например) но владельцем (или если оно не находится в открытом доступе для всех) оно (сообщество) не является, то ВК ничего не отправит. Аналогично если использовался ваш ключ доступа но к данному контенту у вас нет доступа.

Comment: Вопрос, а к чему тут `url` если его нет в методе `messages.send`

Comment: Используется ацесс кей отправителя вложения, отправка фото, видео, музыки работает с помощью данного метода, url не нужен, забыл стереть